# Send value via bluetooth writeValueWithResponse return undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth

I send hex value with writeValueWithResponse function from chrome and i get undefined
when i try with with the app serial bluetooth terminal in android i succeed to get hex value in return from cellocator device

```
let characteristic;// other function make sure instance here
let request = '4D324300000000000000000000';
let request2 = '4D3243000000000000000000000D0A';

function sendValue() {

       // const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      //  const data = encoder.encode(request);

    //let buffer = new Uint8Array(request.match(/../g).map(h=>parseInt(h,16))).buffer

let array = new Uint8Array(request.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
  return parseInt(h, 16)
}))

       characteristic.writeValueWithResponse(array)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('writeValue res ' + res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('writeValue error ' + error);
        });
     
    } else {
        console.log('Characteristic not available');
    }
}
```